# It is possible to select table from database of remote server2 even you are in the remote server1, Not in local server?

Tags: mysql, remote-server, federated

I have Remote_Server1 and Remote_Server2. From Remote_Server1 i want to select tables in the database of Remote_Server2
It is possible? If yes, How?

I try to use federated engine but it only in local server. I did not use local i want to use the remote server in my program.
If the solution is to enable federated engine in Remote server, How can I enabled it in my desktop?
I am new at Mysql.

Comment: What to you want to achieve by 'selecting tables'?

Comment: I want to create view. That's why i want to select table in another remote server

Comment: You could copy the tables from database2 to database1 and sync them periodically with a CRON job. Could you edit your question, as it is not very understandable what you are trying to achieve

Comment: The table and the database are in another server. There are on different server